# What is the equivalent of dblarr(3,3) in C#?

Tags: c#, idl-programming-language

How can I convert this to C# equivalent?

```
    togeolat=dblarr(3,3)
    togeolat[0,0]=cos(!DPI/2-Dlat)
    togeolat[0,2]=sin(!DPI/2-Dlat)
    togeolat[2,0]=-sin(!DPI/2-Dlat)
    togeolat[2,2]=cos(!DPI/2-Dlat)
    togeolat[1,1]=1.
```

Is it just a 3 x 3 matrix with elements in this configuration?

00 , 01 , 02

10 , 11 , 12

20 , 21 , 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
double[,] array = new double[3, 3];
```

Assign value:

```
array[0,0] = Math.Cos(!DPI/2-Dlat);
```

Reference:

- [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)